# Good App to Download Subtitles for Windows

Tags: windows, subtitles

What is a good program to download synced subtitles for my movies while allowing me to specify the language I want?

Answer (score 6):

**[SubDownloader](http://subdownloader.net/)** is a program for automatic download/upload subtitles for videofiles (DIVX,MPEG,AVI,VOB,etc) and DVD's using fast hashing.

> Providing a friendly interface, users
>   have a better movie experience since
>   searching for subtitles is no longer
>   dull or boring. SubDownloader follows
>   the KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid)
>   priciple. You just want to watch a
>   good movie, right?! So, subtitle
>   searching and matching for your movies
>   should be a simple task. It is now!
>   :-)

some key features:

Fast hashing algorithm (27 GB movies/7 seconds)

Recursively folders search

Autodetect language of the subtitles

Upload entire series seasons subtitles in less than 1 minute

*SubDownloader (for Windows) is shareware.*

if they're not in sync, you can use **[Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw)** to sync the subs with the movie or use a media player that allows for subtitle speed adjustment during playback (e.g. **[SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)**)

*Subtitle Workshop is freeware.*

*SMPlayer is open source freeware, a portable version is available.*

Comment: Actually SubDownloader is shareware.

Comment: rather looks like open source to me, since they're giving the source code away.

Comment: Mac and Linux is free, they only charge for the Windows version.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of [BSPlayer](http://www.bsplayer.org/) has this function built in. However it only checks opensubtitles.org, I'm guessing they will add more sites in next versions.

Comment: Thanks, it has been a long time since I used BSPlayer. The downloaded legends are only in memory thought, I want to save them permanently.

Comment: Subtitles are downloaded into cache directory, which is located in user's data folder, %AppData%\BSplayer\cache\

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use a combination of [Subtitle Search](http://sourceforge.net/projects/subtitlesearch/) and [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw) to easily find and process subtitles. With Subtitle Search, you input a title and it searches for the IMDB record of that movie to verify the correct movie. You can put in different settings (what providers you want to search, what language you want, so on and so forth).

It then searches several subtitle databases (including, but not limited to, OpenSubtitles.org) using your settings and provides a comprehensive list of subtitle downloads if there are any.

Now, sometimes these subtitles will work flawlessly, and that's great. More often than not, however, the subtitles will be played too fast or too slow (in my experience, it seems like all the videos I have are playing 24 FPS, but all the subtitles are run in 25 FPS, making them too fast). Or, perhaps the video you have starts immediately into the action while the subtitles have a long pause for opening credits and such. This is what Subtitle Workshop is for.

You can easily change the FPS playback of the subtitles with two clicks, and ditto for shifting the start and end times. It's very intuitive and does all the hard calculations.

Note: both programs are freeware, but Windows-only as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

**I think I know exactly what you're looking for. Once you download this app, you'll know it too. =) It's called [Sublight](http://www.sublight.si).**

Lemme quote a few words about it from Softpedia.com.

"Sublight is a software that enables users to easily search for movie subtitles and download them. 
It can search for subtitles based on several criteria such as movie title, year and more. The results are presented in list from where you can preview and download the title you want.
Here are some key features of "Sublight":

· Auto search subtitle.

· Manual search.

· Internet explorer integration.

· Video playback.

· Support for VLC, BS.Player, Media Player Classic, KMPlayer, GOM player and more.

· Publish new subtitles,

· Auto application updates."

*=) Enjoy.*

Answer (score 1):

I like using [OSCAR](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/oscar). The name is quite smart (OSDb Client Application) and it's simple to use.

Drawbacks: The last version was released a couple of years ago, but it works fine.

Main features:

> quick and accurate search/download of subtitle files for your movies
>
> upload subtitles to help out others in need ;)
>
> multi-language support?
>
> Windows Explorer integration
>
> command-line parameters?
>
> proxy support
>
> IMDb support
>
> drag-n-drop support

I tried Sublight and SubDownloader2 before. SubDownloader2 isn't free for the Windows platform and I found Sublight a little cumbersome when I was testing it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for a tool for automatic subtitles downloading for my favorite TV shows. A few days ago I found an excellent tool - http://github.com/KonishchevDmitry/pysd. For now it the best tool for me, so I recommend it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the marvelous features offered by [Sub Downloader](http://subdownloader.net/) are:

1. Automatic subtitle download
2. Play movies directly from Sub Downloader
3. Download subtitles in your favorite languages
4. Independent search
5. Upload your own subtitles

Comment: Except it is not free nor really shareware, more of a nagware.

Answer (score 0):

SPlayer is a good software which downloads subtitles automagically. It allows to choose between different subtitles tracks.

Apart from  that, I don't see another solution than searching the web for subtitles... tvsubtitle.net for instance.

Comment: http://opensubtitles.org has a large repository of subtitles

Answer (score 0):

Well, not to answer my own question (I'm still looking for something that's better) but [Kantaris](http://www.kantaris.org/) is free and much better than the alternatives mentioned here so far.

Normally it finds synced subs in several languages from OpenSubtitles and I'm happy with it, the only drawback is that there isn't a option to actually save the downloaded subtitles (they are temporarily stored in a obscure folder).

If anyone knows a better free alternative that allows me to save the subtitles please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You know what, you already use the best - Browser . Open your browser, type subscene.com> find what subtitles you want :)
It's the best way I think :)